Pointcloud/Mesh Analysis of an arch shaped object and its endpoints
I am looking into finding the endpoints of arch shaped objects that in some cases are asymmetrical (Think of a cave's opening), and this is the solution I came up with.
I am quite new to this, so sorry for my crude illustrations.
I am using python, with the Open3D and Trimesh libraries.
Are there better/less convoluted ways to solve this issue?
This is my process;
NOTE: I have initially tried generalizing the point cloud to fit a curve equation (Catenary, Parabola, Cubic etc.) but It does not work so well with the asymmetrical arches.
I am using this model for example, these are the areas with the desired endpoints I want;

Assume that the arch is laid down on the X/Y plane.
So First, I compute the centroid of the object, and the width of the object using trimesh's bounding box feature.
import trimesh

mesh = trimesh.load('mesh_path')

obb = mesh.bounding_box_oriented

obb_transform = obb.primitive.transform

obb_extents = obb.primitive.extents

sorted_extents = sorted(obb_extents, reverse=True)
length, width, height = sorted_extents



Next, I raycast a ray from the centroid that is the same length as the length measurement of the mesh, and do this at 90 degree intervals in the X and Y axis. This is a visual representation;

Code looks something like this;
# Define ray directions at 90-degree intervals around the XY plane
directions = [
    [1, 0, 0],  # Positive X
    [0, 1, 0],  # Positive Y
    [-1, 0, 0], # Negative X
    [0, -1, 0]  # Negative Y
]

# Length of the ray, set to be the maximum of the length and width of the OBB
ray_length = max(length, width)

# Function to check if a ray collides with the mesh
def check_collision(ray_origin, ray_direction):
    ray = trimesh.ray.ray_pyembree.RayMeshIntersector(mesh)
    locations, index_ray, index_tri = ray.intersects_location(
        ray_origins=[ray_origin],
        ray_directions=[ray_direction],
        multiple_hits=False)
    return len(locations) > 0

# Iterate through each direction and check for collisions
non_colliding_direction = None
for direction in directions:
    ray_direction = np.array(direction) * ray_length
    if not check_collision(centroid, ray_direction):
        non_colliding_direction = direction
        break

if non_colliding_direction is not None:
    print(f"Non-colliding direction: {non_colliding_direction}")
else:
    print("All directions collide with the object.")

And finally, for the direction that did not collide with the object, I place another reference point that is inline with the centroid at the edge of the bounding box.
From this reference point, I send out two rays in opposing directions that are perpendicular to the non-collision ray, and I get my endpoints (hooray)

